# Meteor Spiderable with phantomjs doesn't show yield content

Tags: meteor, seo, web-crawler, phantomjs, iron-router

Following this article METEOR SEO GUIDE https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-12-the-complete-guide-to-seo/20:

I have installed Spiderable (meteor add spiderable), phantomjs (apt-get install phantomjs), making sure all of my publications have a return. I'm working with meteor 1.0.0, and iron-router 1.0.0.

Everything seems to be working well, when I open localhost/?_escaped_fragment_= I get the static content generated by phantomjs (no errors), but the content inside {{>yield}} is not included. If I try to load any data directly to layout phantomjs reads it as well.

How can I make the content included in {{>yield}} readable for spiders?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Iron router 0.9.4 version, but I can't still fix it with latest iron router <=1.0.0 version.